# How can I create the Stack Overflow logo in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, logo

How can I proceed to create the Stack Overflow logo in Inkscape?

[image: Orange rectangles falling out of three sides of a rectangle]

I have tried the following, but how can I rotate the orange rectangles?

[image: The logo but the "stack" isn't tilted]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not the down voter. People often downvote questions when they feel a question shows no research or effort.  To avoid this you should at least mention what you have tried or what has failed. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Hi, thank you. I am a total noob to inkscape, and have no idea to get started to replicate that. I am just curious to see if that's possible in Inkscape.

Comment: I down voted. Insulting down voters is certainly not going to make me wary of downvoting poor questions in the future. This question shows **zero** effort or research. If you don't want to garner my down vote.. then at least explain what you have tried and where you are having difficulty. Have you tried merely drawing a series of rectangles in Inkscape? Tried rotating things? What possible benefit is there in recreating a logo which is not yours and is already freely available in vector form? What *aspects* of this logo are you struggling to create?

Comment: One should *at a minimum* put as much effort into a question as you are asking others to expend for any answer. This isn't an automated service. You are asking other individuals, on a volunteer basis, to share their time and knowledge. This is not a "tutorial on demand" web site.

Comment: If you know nothing about Inkscape it would honestly probably be more productive to follow some basic tutorials first There are lots on youtube.  A good channel is Logos by Nick.

Comment: @BillyKerr: I have added an edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That makes your question answerable now.

Comment: @Scott: I have added an edit. And sorry, that's not a insult it's just a reminder (downvote and run).

Comment: Down voting does **not** require commenting.. the down vote itself **is** the comment. ... And "insecure" certainly rings of an insult. FYI.. the simple edit you've made, makes this no longer worthy of my down vote. See how easy that was? `:)`

Comment: @Scott: Thank you :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Delete all your orange rectangles except the bottom one.

1. With the Select Objects tool <kbd>S</kbd> Click once on the orange rectangle to see the object handles, then click a second time to show the rotation handles.
2. Click and drag the Rotation centre off to the right. Note: you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you drag it to constrain the move horizontally.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the orange rectangle
4. While holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, click and drag the rotation handle to rotate at 15 degree increments.

Repeat steps 3 and 4 until complete.

Example

[image]

In your example I also notice the grey box is a little wonky.

An easier way to make that would be to instead draw a rectangle with a thick stroke and no fill. Convert to paths using *Path > Object to Path*. With the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, select the top segment and hit the Delete Segment button in the Controls along the top

[image]

Comment: Still wrong... its "center"  - silly Europeans `:)` Merry Holiday thing!

Comment: @Scott - I wish I was a "European".  Sadly no more since the Brexit disaster thing. But yeah, Season's Greetings to you an yours!,

Comment: @Scott well if we use word "pivot" then it is less ambigious and no less correct. Also it is more natural to talk of moving a pivot point.

Comment: @joojaa - anyway, wondering why I am here on Christmas day, when I should be preparing dinner!  Merry Christmas, Seasons' Greetings, Happy Yuletide or whatever, and don't catch any diseases anyone!

Comment: @Scott: now that my question got 10 upvotes, I want to be a moderator, and [I want all the credit without any blame](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/cf878eb9-005d-437b-8cbf-4a2ae1aad9ab).

Comment: @OK-Validation `:)` ya got lucky it hit Hot Network Questions and mentions SO `:)` You can have the credit..`:)`